# Why does this recursive image comparison take less then primitive iterative one? (JAVA 8)

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I have run into a little situation that puzzles me. Would someone be able to explain it?

I have written an algorithm in Java that compares two images by first comparing the two middle columns of the two images, then comparing the two middle rows of the two images, and then recursively comparing the four remaining quadrants in the two images.

Now, for some reason my test tells me that my algorithm is quicker then the primitive comparison which simply iterates over each row and each column.

I would have thought that the iterative approach would be faster as the number of comparisons is the same, while in the recursive approach we're doing additional calculations to work out the four quadrants and the middle row and column.

I have done a separate test ( which I won't include) to check that the algorithm does in fact go over every pixel in the image and it does.

Is there something I'm missing in my implementation or is there something about the Java compiler that's producing this result?

Here's the code:

Algo:

```
public boolean areIdentical(BufferedImage image1, BufferedImage image2) {
        int height = image1.getHeight();
        int width = image2.getWidth();
        for(int y : new int[]{0, height-1}){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                if(!compareColors(image1.getRGB(x,y), image2.getRGB(x,y))) return false;
            }
        }
        for(int x : new int[]{0,width-1}){
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                if(!compareColors(image1.getRGB(x,y), image2.getRGB(x,y))) return false;
            }
        }
        return areIdenticalRecursiveCross(image1, image2, new BoxCoordinates(1,1, width-2,height-2));
    }


public boolean areIdenticalRecursiveCross(BufferedImage image1, BufferedImage image2, BoxCoordinates boxToCheck){
        int height = boxToCheck.getHeight();
        int width = boxToCheck.getWidth();
        int startX= boxToCheck.getX();
        int startY=boxToCheck.getY();
        if(height == 1 || height == 2 || width == 1 || width == 2){
            for (int x = startX; x < startX+width; x++) {
                for (int y = startY; y < startY+height; y++) {
                    if(!compareColors(image1.getRGB(x,y),image2.getRGB(x,y))) return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else{
            int newWidth = width/2 - 1 +width%2;
            for(int x = startX+newWidth; x <= startX+width/2; x++){
                for(int y = startY; y < startY+height; y++){
                    if(!compareColors(image1.getRGB(x,y),image2.getRGB(x, y))) return false;
                }
            }
            int newHeight = height/2 - 1 + height%2;
            for(int y = startY + newHeight; y <= startY + height/2; y++){
                for(int x = startX; x < width+startX; x++){
                    if(!compareColors(image1.getRGB(x,y),image2.getRGB(x, y))) return false;
                }
            }
            return     areIdenticalRecursiveCross(image1, image2,new BoxCoordinates(startX, startY, newWidth, newHeight))
                    && areIdenticalRecursiveCross(image1, image2,new BoxCoordinates(startX + width/2+1, startY, newWidth, newHeight))
                    && areIdenticalRecursiveCross(image1, image2,new BoxCoordinates(startX, startY + height/2+1, newWidth, newHeight))
                    && areIdenticalRecursiveCross(image1, image2,new BoxCoordinates(startX+ width/2+1, startY+height/2+1, newWidth, newHeight));
        }
    }

   public boolean compareColors(int c1, int c2){
        return c1 == c2;
    }
```

Test:

```
public void testAreIdentical() throws Exception {
    BufferedImage screen = takeScreenshot();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean primitive = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<1;i++) {
        primitive = primitive(screen, screen);
    }
    long end =System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Primitive took: " + (end-start)/1000.0 + " returning " + primitive);

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean recursive = false;
    for (int i =0; i< 1;i++) {
        recursive = matcher.areIdentical(screen, screen);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Failgorithm took: " + (end-start)/1000.0 + " returning " + recursive);

}

public boolean primitive(BufferedImage image1, BufferedImage image2){
    for (int x = 0; x < image1.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image1.getHeight(); y++) {
            if(image1.getRGB(x,y)!=image2.getRGB(x,y)) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Test Result:

```
Primitive took: 0.161 returning true
Failgorithm took: 0.127 returning true
Failgorithm 2 took: 0.168 returning true
```

Interestingly if I change the algorithm to only check a single middle row and column on each recursive step, I get a worse result(Failgorithm 3).

Comment: My first guess, besides guessing that something in all the complexity of the recursive algorithm is wrong, is that the differences between the images are at pixels that the recursive algorithm checks before the iterative one.

Comment: Where does the Failgorithm 2 output come from?

Comment: @user2357112 I first thought that about the data - but the images are "reported to be identical" (which I am assuming is true).

Comment: This primitive benchmark is flawed like most micros in that it doesn't do enough iterations, let the JVM warm up, or interleave runs. Such may (or may not) affect the observed results.

Comment: I am comparing an image to itself.

Comment: It must be something to do with the way concurrency is handled, the recursive approach thread must be getting more run time.

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of the recursive and iterative tests?

Comment: switching order produces the same result

Comment: What if you switch the order of the x and y loops in the iterative algorithm?